# node.js WebSocket server compatible with Chrome 14+ and with Safari?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I've been using the node.js WebSocket implementation from http://github.com/ncr/node.ws.js, but it's only compatible with the `hixie-76` version of the protocol, as implemented by Safari 5.0.1.

I also need to work with Chrome, which now implements the official protocol per [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Does anyone know a server-side implementation for node.js which is compatible with both `hixie-76` and `hybi-17` (aka "version 13") ?

Please do *not* recommend Socket.IO - it's not real WebSockets!

Implementations I know of that do not work (at the time of writing) are:

- https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node
- https://github.com/ncr/node.ws.js
- https://github.com/Guille/node.websocket.js
- https://github.com/einaros/ws

Comment: I don't know of any node.js server that supports both Hixie and HyBi/IETF 6455 but for reference, here are ones that support just the new version: https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node, https://github.com/einaros/ws I am also interested in a solution that supports both so that I can use it for my Node.js implementation of [websockify](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify) so hopefully somebody else knows of an answer.

Comment: thanks for the second one - it wasn't on my list (but now is)

Comment: What do you mean Socket.IO is not a real WebSockets? Of course it is, but it does some other things if WebSocket communication is impossible.

Comment: @freakish I mean that you can't use native WebSockets in the client to talk to a Socket.IO server unless you also implement the Socket.IO protocol layer in the client.  Socket.IO sits _on top of_ WebSockets (or something else if those aren't available).

Comment: @Alnitak Well, Socket.IO is not a protocol, it is better to call it WebSocket wrapper (as I believe we do agree that all in all the communication goes through WebSockets). But you're right although I do not understand why this is bad? Why can't you use it? Socket.IO is definetly the most mature and powerful WebSocket/Node.js library.

Comment: @freakish no, it really _is_ a protocol in its own right.  It presents a _WebSocket-like_ API to the programmer but can run over several different lower layer protocols, including "real" WebSockets.  In my case it's an unnecessary abstraction, although admittedly I am struggling because of the lack of consistent client-side support for the official IETF RFC 6455 protocol.

Comment: @Alnitak Fair enough. Still I would recommend using Socket.IO. The "unnecessary abstraction" is rather lightweighted and the advantages are rather significant.

Comment: @freakish the downside is that it requires re-writing both my client and server code, which _was_ working until Chrome 14 came out.

Comment: @Alnitak I see, well that's the price you have to pay. :) That is if you go that way. I wish you luck!

Answer (score 1):

Since seeing this question yesterday, I spent a bit of time implementing hixie-76 support (although I'd rather stick to hybi only) in ws.

See if version 0.4.2, available through npm or on https://github.com/einaros/ws helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this library: https://github.com/wcauchois/websocket-fallback

It uses Worlize/WebSocket-Node for browsers that implement the newer versions of the protocol, and miksago/node-websocket-server for older browsers (Safari, I'm looking at you!)

You just use one API and it transparently deals with the various browsers/connections/libraries for you.